# Parse findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock not work with Facebook SDK completionHandler

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I use follow code to make some actions when Facebook SDK return completionHandler:

```
FBRequestConnection.startWithGraphPath("me?fields=first_name,last_name,email", completionHandler: {
    (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        var query = PFQuery(className: "users")

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ 
           (object, error) -> Void in

           . . . some actions . . .

        })
})
```

But when Facebook SDK returned from authorisation screen to App, Parse method "findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock" did not work. He only work when App screen is visible.

How to make this method work, even when Facebook switch to App?

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"?

Comment: Application ignore this method. I think this happens when Facebook SDK switching to App, and in "switching time" start execute completionHandler closure. Maybe findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock required only visible/active App.

Comment: In this case maybe you can try to wrap your code (I'm not sure, that findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock or the whole startWithGraphPath) in an withExtendedLifetime function, described as here: http://swiftdoc.org/func/withExtendedLifetime/

Comment: Maybe problem with *asynchronously*? Maybe Grand Central Dispatch can help?

Comment: in your AppDelegate, do you handle the return URL from Facebook login?